# What is wrong with the following "proof" that $\sim$ is reflexive?

Tags: equivalence-relations

Let ~ be a symmetric and transitive relation on a set A. What is wrong with the folloing "proof" that $\sim$ is reflexive?

> Proof: $a\sim b$ implies $b\sim a$ by symmetry; then $a\sim b$ and $b\sim a$ imply that $a\sim a$ by transitivity, thus $a\sim a$.)

Comment: I have created a [canonical Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802279/), which is meant to address this question, and others like it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We must have $\forall a \in A$, $a \sim a$.

You just proved that if $\exists b$ s.t. $a \sim b$, then $a \sim a$. Why is there such $b$?

For example, the empty relation satisfies symmetry and transitiveness, but the lack of existence of something to "apply" them yields non-reflexivity.

Comment: In the book I am studying algebra, happens that following the aforementioned question, comes this:    
  
Can you suggest an alternative of property 1 [reflexivity] which will insure us that properties 2 [symmetry] and 3 [transitiveness] do imply property 1?  
  
The first question I answered saying that we can consider an $x$ in $A$ such that there is no $y$ that satisfies $x$ ~ $y$, hence there is no guarantee that reflexivity follows necessarily from the other two properties. But I can't imagine such an alternative as asked in this second item.

Comment: @izzorts Sorry for the late response. I think the alternative that your question wants is requiring that every $a \in A$ is related to someone (from which reflexivity follows, as the "flawed" argument now applies). Another alternative is requiring that there exists a function $f \subset R$, where $R$ is the relation (both requirements are equivalent assuming choice).